# How to Handle SQLlite database changes on upgrade version of app using codename one

Tags: codenameone

On upgrade the app existing data in the device database is lost. How to handle the sqllite database on database tables alters and newly added table with out losing the existing database changes.

note: if we changes sqllite database name on new upgrade we lost existing data.

Is there any abstract class SQLiteOpenHelper android like in functionality in codename one  .

Please help on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It shouldn't delete your database when the app is upgraded.  What platform is this on (Android or iOS?)  Did you possibly change the name of your database between versions?

Comment: if we change the name we lost the existing data from devices, we need to have the old data already saved in the device.

Comment: Are you changing the name of your database or the name of your app?

Comment: Yes we are changing the database name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataAcess Library for CN1 by shannah has a function, where one can handle exactly this case.

`https://github.com/shannah/cn1-data-access-lib#database-creation-and-versioning`